# I can't seem to run an array for a string variable

Tags: c, arrays, string

I've run this code countless times and I'm not sure what's wrong with it. It won't display the 'subj' variable whenever I run the code and choose the '1. Display' option. All I get is the error 'divide error' 'abnormal program termination '→ '

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

char subj[20], name[20], course[20], studentid[20];
float grade[20], hold, gu[20], guadd, gpa, temp, median, mode, max, a[20];
int z, i, h, n, tu, c, unit[20], count;

void disp(int n, int unit[], float grade[], char subj[], char name[], char studentid[], char course[])
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("Course: %s\n", course);
    printf("Student ID: %s\n", studentid);
    printf("\n\nSubject\t\t\tUnits\t\t\tFinal Grade\n");

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", subj[i]);
        printf("\t\t\t%d\t\t\t", unit[i]);
        printf("\%.2f\n", grade[i]);
    }
    tu=0;
    guadd=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        gu[i]=grade[i]*unit[i];
        tu+=unit[i];
        guadd+=gu[i];
    }
    gpa=guadd/tu;
    printf("\n\nSemester Grade Point Average:\t\t\t%.2f\n", gpa);
}

int main()
{
clrscr();
printf("Enter Student Name: ");
scanf ("%s", &name);
printf("Enter Student ID: ");
scanf ("%s", &studentid);
printf("Enter Course: ");
scanf ("%s", &course);
printf("Please Enter the Amount of Subjects Enrolled: ");
scanf ("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nPlease Enter the Subject Name: ");
        scanf("%s", &subj[i]);
        printf("Please Enter the Final Grade for this Subject: ");
        scanf ("%f", &grade[i]);
        printf("Please Enter Number of Units for this Subject: ");
        scanf ("%d", &unit[i]);
    }
clrscr();
do
{
printf("\nPlease Choose an Option:\n\n1. Display Grades with GPA\n2. Ascending Order of Grades\n3. Descending Order of Grades\n4. Median and Mode\n5.EXIT\n\nChoice: ");
scanf ("%d", &z);
clrscr();

switch(z)
{
    case 1: disp(n, unit, grade, subj, name, studentid, course);
            break;
    case 2: ascending(n, grade);
            break;
    case 3: descending(n, grade);
            break;
    case 4: medmod(n, grade);
            break;
}
}
while (z!=5);


    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

P.S. I'm new to this so I don't really know what the issue is. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried gets and puts but it gives me the error 'can't convert int to char'

Comment: You can use multi dimensional arrays to store n subjects,grades and units. A better approach would be to create an array of structures for subject with members subject name, grade and units. Currently, if the no of subjects enrolled is >1, the last subject and its details entered would be shown

Comment: Functions ascending descending medmod are not here , are they in another file ?

Comment: `scanf("%s", &subj[i]);` This statement makes sense only if `subj` is a double dimension array. However, you need to pre-define the max length of each string in the 2d array. Instead you could use pointers

Comment: ascending, descending, and medmod had no errors and were not in  any way connected to the disp function so I just didn't include them to keep the code as short as possible. @BobRun

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari I did try to do subj[20][20] but it gave me an error 'can't convert char[20] to *char'

Comment: @OHenry, make sure you have changed the function prototype too (from `char subj[]` to `char subj[][20]`)

Comment: Ye violate *Commandment No. 6* of [10 Commandments for C Programmers](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html). Ye be warned... Also, avoid the use of the old DOS `conio.h` completely. It is 100% non-portable.  Use the functions from `stdio.h`. Don't worry about `clrscr()` and you are simply using `getch()` to hold the terminal window open, so `getchar()` will work as well.

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari I just tried it and it works! Thank you so much!!! You just saved my final project for this term! Awesome!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I didn't know that. I was just using what our professor lectured us on. I will look into this some more and will be following it moving forward. Thanks!

Comment: It is just a reminder to ***Validate Every Input*** (especially User-Input, and especially when using the New C Programmer trap `scanf`). Example, `if (scanf ("%s", &name) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid input - name.\n", stderr); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }`. It will save you no end of frustration and hours of time in the future. (thus the reason behind Commandment No. 6)

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's for your own sake.

Comment: @OHenry - food for thought [Example Student Grades](https://paste.opensuse.org/69213052) Just take it one piece at a time. When you need to coordinate different types as a single object - think `struct`. In your case you have `students` which is one struct, but then each student has subject which is a second struct nested inside the first. You simply create an *array-of-struct* in each case. An array of struct `student` holds individual student data, and each of those contains an array of struct `subjects` which holds the subject info for each student. Enjoy.

Comment: how are we to reproduce the problem, so we can help you debug it when you have not posted all the code.  BTW:  `conio.h` is not available in the 'real' world Therefore suggest you remove that `#include` statement and use standard library functions

Answer (score 1):

Some changes I made to your code and it works.

Replace `char subj[20]` by `char *subj[20]` since you need an array of strings, not an array of characters which would be a single string. Then, allocate memory to each of them dynamically (used `malloc` from C's `stdlib.h`), say at-least for 100 chars.

Also, the `gcc` compiler generates warnings good enough to know what's going on, so it becomes quite clear to fix your arguments to `printf` and `scanf` functions.

PS : Since `conio.h` is non-portable, I removed it and its functions from the code.

Modified code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *subj[20];
char name[20], course[20], studentid[20];
float grade[20], hold, gu[20], guadd, gpa, temp, median, mode, max, a[20];
int z, i, h, n, tu, c, unit[20], count;

void disp(int n, int unit[], float grade[], char *subj[], char name[],
      char studentid[], char course[]) {
  printf("Name: %s\n", name);
  printf("Course: %s\n", course);
  printf("Student ID: %s\n", studentid);
  printf("\n\nSubject\t\t\tUnits\t\t\tFinal Grade\n");

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%s", subj[i]);
    printf("\t\t\t%d\t\t\t", unit[i]);
    printf("\%.2f\n", grade[i]);
  }
  tu = 0;
  guadd = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    gu[i] = grade[i] * unit[i];
    tu += unit[i];
    guadd += gu[i];
  }
  gpa = guadd / tu;
  printf("\n\nSemester Grade Point Average:\t\t\t%.2f\n", gpa);
}

int main() {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    subj[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  printf("Enter Student Name: ");
  scanf("%s", name);
  printf("Enter Student ID: ");
  scanf("%s", studentid);
  printf("Enter Course: ");
  scanf("%s", course);
  printf("Please Enter the Amount of Subjects Enrolled: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("%s %s %s %d", name, studentid, course, n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\nPlease Enter the Subject Name: ");
    scanf("%s", subj[i]);
    printf("%s", subj[i]);
    printf("Please Enter the Final Grade for this Subject: ");
    scanf("%f", &grade[i]);
    printf("Please Enter Number of Units for this Subject: ");
    scanf("%d", &unit[i]);
  }
  do {
    printf("\nPlease Choose an Option:\n\n1. Display Grades with GPA\n2. "
       "Ascending Order of Grades\n3. Descending Order of Grades\n4. "
       "Median and Mode\n5.EXIT\n\nChoice: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);

    switch (z) {
      case 1:
        disp(n, unit, grade, subj, name, studentid, course);
        break;
      case 2:
        break;
      case 3:
        descending(n, grade);
        break;
      case 4:
        medmod(n, grade);
        break;
    }
  } while (z != 5);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: char name[20], course[20], studentid[20]; are global variables , in main() you store into the global variables then you call disp() , there is no need for char name[20], course[20], studentid[20]; to be passed to disp() , they are global.

Comment: @BobRun Yes, true. Though I didn't focus on that since that wasn't exactly the pressing issue for OP.

Comment: @jarvis I wasn't critical of your fix, only trying to inform OP of flaws that could be detrimental to his project score.